# How can i get the list of firebase realtime database valueslist to flutter dropdown menu?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

How can i get the values listed in firebase realtime database to a drop down menu in flutter application. I want to add all values as a String to a list which can be used as a dropdown items in flutter widget.
After going through the flutter firebase documentation, i can only get the values but not as an individual entities. When i try to add them to a list, it adds all on them to the first list item.

```
getLocation() async {
  DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('Admin/Cities/');
  DatabaseEvent event = await ref.once();
  print(event.snapshot.value.toString());
  print(event.snapshot.value.runtimeType);
  print(event.snapshot.children.runtimeType);
  List cityList = [];
  cityList.add(event.snapshot.value);
  print(cityList[0]);
  print(cityList);
  print(cityList.length);
  print(cityList[0]);
  print('list');  
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If not, the Firebase documentation is typically a good place to get started: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/overview, but there are also quite a few tutorials out there: https://www.google.com/search?q=flutter+How+can+i+show+a+list+of+firebase+realtime+database+values+to+dropdown+menu%3F

Comment: I have tried to get the data as per the firebase.flutter documentation you provided earlier. Using the below code final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
final snapshot = await ref.child('users/$userId').get();
if (snapshot.exists) {
    print(snapshot.value);
} else {
    print('No data available.');
}

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the results i get when i run the code i get from the flutter firebase realtime database.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're reading all cities in one go, the snapshot you get contains multiple child snapshots. You'll want to loop over the children of the snapshot, and process each in turn:

```
getLocation() async {
  DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('Admin/Cities/');
  DatabaseEvent event = await ref.once();
  var snapshot = event.snapshot;
  List cityList = [];
  snapshot.children.forEach((child) {
    print(child.key);
    cityList.add(child.value);
  })
  print(cityList);
  print(cityList.length);
}
```

Comment: There should be quite a few examples here: https://www.google.com/search?q=Show+data+from+Firebase+Realtime+Database+in+StreamBuilder. If you're struggling to make that work, I recommend opening a new question showing the code of what you tried.